# How to remove error of rake aborted?

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I am using rails 3 and I am trying to create new model but I am having error as rake aborted 
I tried giving different model name and I gave different fields also in each model creation .
I am new on ruby on rails please help

Comment: What is your command to create new model?

Comment: Can you post your error pls.

Comment: Rake aborted!. Multiple migrations have the name CreateRstuds

Answer (score 0):

check if migration files are having timestamp appended.

Answer (score 0):

You got this error because you have more than one migration file with the same name.

Check your db/migrate folder, and see if there are two migrations with the same name:

```
20131007030431_CreateRstuds.rb
20131012173735_CreateRstuds.rb
```

Remove one of them. And then - try to migrate again.

**EDIT:**

Maybe your schema migration is not updated with latest migration.
you can drop the database and create it again, only if you are starting a app and there is no data in your table, or if it's somehow recoverable or worthless.
**WARNING**: if you have real data, DON'T do it! You will lose all your data!

```
rake db:drop
rake db:create
rake db:migrate
```

Comment: C:\Sites\stp>rake db:migrate
==  CreateRstuds: migrating ===================================================
-- create_table(:rstuds)
NOTICE:  CREATE TABLE will create implicit sequence "rstuds_id_seq1" for serial
column "rstuds.id"
rake aborted!
An error has occurred, this and all later migrations canceled:

PG::DuplicateTable: ERROR:  relation "rstuds" already exists
: CREATE TABLE "rstuds" ("id" serial primary key, "firstname" ..)


Tasks: TOP => db:migrate
(See full trace by running task with --trace)
I am getting above mention error now, I tried your way but sorry sir

Comment: What `rake db:migrate --trace` gives you?